# The fonts on Android Studio are strange

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ide

The fonts in the Android Studio app are strange to me.
I mean the software's fonts, like the menu's fonts and etc

The image below can help you more...

[image]

Comment: Is this a freshly installed AS? Are you using Open JDK?

Comment: is this a same issue with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034206/weird-font-while-installing-android-studio?